# Python replace \) to )

Tags: python, string, replace

I read a file, and get a string `line = "\(\)"`, which I want to change to `()`.

```
>>> line = "\(\)"
>>> line.replace("\(", '(')
'(\\)'
>>> line.replace("\)", ')')
'\\()'
>>>
```

As above, I got a `'\\()'`.

What should I do to get the `()`?

---

`line` may include another word begin with `\`.

Comment: Get rid of the backslashes.  `line = line.replace("\\", "")`

Comment: Also realize that '\' is being displayed as '\\' and `str.replace` does not edit the string itself but returns a new string. Regarding the second point, `line.replace("\(", '(').replace("\)", ')')` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close: `line.replace("\(", '(')` will replace `\(` with `(`; and `line.replace("\)", ')')` will replace `\)` with `)`, but you still need to assign it to your result:

```
>>> line = "\(\)"
>>> line = line.replace("\(", '(')
>>> line
'(\\)'
>>> line = line.replace("\)", ')')
>>> line
'()'
```

or, in one step instead of two, you can chain:

```
>>> line = "\(\)"
>>> line = line.replace("\(", '(').replace("\)", ')')
>>> line
'()'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace the `\` character. To do this, you have to escape it:

```
"\(\)".replace('\\','')
'()'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another way:

```
>>> line = "\(\)"
>>> 
>>> slash = "\ ".replace(" ","")
>>> line.replace(slash, "")
'()'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Python String replace() Method to handle this:

```
line = "\(\)"
line = line.replace("\\", "")
print line # It prints ()
```